# Prevent two functions from running asynchronous - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, visual-studio-code

I'm currently working on a chatbot that solves problems. So I have written my code but there are two functions running asynchronous. So what I want is for my code to first run a function that checks if a value in the users input equals a value in my array. It then sends a message asking for a classroom where the problem is. Then I want my code to run the second function looping through the users input looking for the classroom mention and then sending a message containing that classroom to the problem solver.

But the problem in my code is that when I mention the classroom these two funcions send a message at the same time, for example:

> **Users input**: "I have a problem with the smartboard"
>
> **Chatbots first message**: "I'm sorry but I didn't understand it. Please write the classroom as the following: L***."
>
> **Chatbots second message**: "Okay...In what classroom is your current problem?"

This is not what I want. What I want looks like this:

> **Users input**: "I have a problem with the smartboard"
>
> **Chatbots message**: "Okay...In what classroom is your current problem?"
>
> **Users input**: "L108"
>
> **But if the classroom isn't in the classrooms array then chatbots message**: "I'm sorry but I didn't understand it. Please write the classroom as the following: L***."

What I tried to do is call the second funtion in the first function but that didn't work, or maybe I did it wrong ;). My code looks like the following:

```
bot.on('message', data => {
    if (data.type !== 'message' || data.subtype === 'bot_message') {
        return;
    }
    handleMessage(data.text);
    findClassroomMention(data.text);
    console.log(data)
});

var digibord =
    {
        name: ["digibord","smartboard","schoolbord"]
    };

function handleMessage(message) {
    digibord.name.forEach((name) => {
        if (name.includes(message)) {
            bericht();
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
}

function bericht() {
    const params = {
        icon_emoji: ':smiley:'
    }
    problem = "digibord"
    bot.postMessageToChannel('general', 'Okay...In what classroom is your current problem?',params);
};

var classrooms = 
    {
        L108: ["L108","108"],
        L208: ["L208","208"]
    };

function findClassroomMention(message) {    
    var found = false   
    for(var ClassroomId in classrooms) {
        for(var term of classrooms[ClassroomId]) {
            if(message.includes(term)) {
                found = ClassroomId;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            const params = {
                icon_emoji: ':smiley:'
            }
            bot.postMessageToChannel('general'," I'm sorry but I didn't understand it. Please write the classroom as the following: L***.", params);
            break;
        }
        if (found) {
            notifyProblemSolver(ClassroomId);
            break;
        }
    }
    return found
};

function notifyProblemSolver(ClassroomId) {
    const params = {
        icon_emoji: ':smiley:'
    }
    bot.postMessageToChannel('caris','We have a problem with '+ problem + ' in ' + ClassroomId, params);
};
```

Any tips on how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't quite understand it properly. When the user first reports about the problem, handleMessage() is executed fully and responds with 'Okay...In what.....' message  and the second method findClassroomMention() doesn't execute fully as it breaks in between. So, then how come the response from second method findClassroomMention() is sent as a response for the first message from user?

Comment: the response of the second method findClassroomMention() is a response to the users input